# Why does this expect code not work?

Tags: expect

Not sure if this is more of a scripting/unix question or a programming one, but I tried on the unix stackexchange and got no responses, so:

The following expect code seems to work; that is, it appears to enter text in answer to the password prompt.  However, the device never actually mounts.

But if I simply enter the command into a shell and type the password in by hand the device mounts successfully.

So I'm curious where the input is actually ending up, as it never seems to 'catch' the password yet doesn't present an error message either?  In fact the output looks exactly the same in both instances, but only in the case of running the command and typing the password manually do I see my files appear over the network.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sudo mount.cifs "//WinPC/My Pictures" /home/LinPC/Desktop/Pictures -o user=Me
expect "Password: " {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    send -s "a_password"
}
```

UPDATE: Got the help I needed to make it work: had to insert 'expect eof' after sending the password so that it doesn't end prematurely.  However I now wish to progress to changing it to 'expect_background' so that I can have the same trigger response to issuing multiple mount commands.  The following ends prematurely, and 'expect eof' at the end causes an error:

```
expect_background "Password:" {
    send "a_password\r"
    expect eof
}
spawn sudo mount.cifs "//WinPC/My Pictures" /home/LinPC/Desktop/Pictures -o user=Me
expect eof
```

What should it look like?

UPDATE: the following code block illustrates the current problem:

```
expect_background "Password: " {
    send "a_password\r"
    expect eof
}
spawn sudo mount.cifs "//WinPC/My Pictures" /home/LinPC/Desktop/Pictures -o user=someone

expect "Password: " {
    send "a_password\r"
    expect eof
}
#The password prompt gets answered by 'expect' but not 'expect_background'.
#If I delete the last 'expect' and insert 'expect eof' it hangs for a short
#while at the password prompt (around 3 seconds) then exits.
#Why?
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: seems the error only occurs if I use expect and not expect_background (it says: expect: spawn id exp6 not open). However the 'Password' prompt does not trigger entering a password and typing it in manually doesn't do anything (probably intentional as the stdin is going to expect?).  'expect' still works though.  I'll edit the OP to show where I'm currently at with this.

Comment: Can you add `exp_internal 1` in code and share the debug output?

Comment: expect: timed out.  Don't know why it's getting a match in one case and not the other; wrong spawn_id perhaps?

Comment: Ok I think the expect_background is being triggered, and expect eof, while showing an error, slowed it down just enough that mount.cifs has time to show its own error code if the device is already mounted.  Otherwise it exits before it has time to mount.  I've confirmed that the script works if I just put 'sleep 2' at the end!  Is there any way to make expect wait for all spawned processes to finish (where expect eof is complaining that spawn id exp6 not open)?

Comment: Also seems to only work if I put the spawn statement before the expect_background statement.

Comment: I added -i spawn_id to the expect_background and now it works when the spawn occurs afterward--I thought it would have done that anyway by default?  It still needs the sleep statement at the end and expect eof doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one more `expect` statement after sending the password.

```
send -s "a_password\r"
expect eof
```

The `eof` will make the `Expect` to wait till the end of program.

Comment: At first this did not work, seemingly hanging at the end of the password, but then I realised I have to enter '\r' at the end of the password and then it does work.  Thanks for that.

Comment: One other thing though: if I switch to using expect_background, I think the script ends before it gets a chance to respond to the password.  Putting 'expect eof' at the outermost scope causes an error.  Not sure how to make this work (I want it to answer multiple commands with the same password) EDIT: updated the OP to reflect this question